# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(MyComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>,

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am setting up React-Redux to my web application, I have been getting a Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Register)".

I figured maybe I would have to pass the store that I created in [[2]] `store.js` and it worked but I haven't seen it done this way online and when I tried using redux DevTools it kept showing no store found.

I thought the purpose of connect() was to wrap around the component and access the global state in redux via mapStateToProps. If someone could point me in the right direction or possibly explain why I am getting this error would great!

Something things I have tried:

1. Since I was had a container component LoginContainer.js (which I could access via connect()(LoginContainer) I thought I would able to access the state here and pass down the props to register.js component and then propagate up state changes.
2. I have been thinking of changing register.js to a functional component because maybe this may be affecting it somehow?

I have been reading about context and how by using `<Provider store={store}>` at the index.js it should have allowed access to the Redux store via connect(mapState,MapDispach)(Component) however I still cannot distinguish how or when I am losing to context to Provider.

```js
//index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```js
// App.js 

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import LoginContainer from "./containers/login";
class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
          <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
          <Switch>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginContainer} />
          </Switch>
          </header>
          </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
// LoginContainer.js 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Register from "../componets/Registration/register";
import Login from "../componets/Login/login";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";
class LoginContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        //some local UI states
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ToggleContainer">
          <div className={"toggle"}>
            <Button.Group>
              <Button
                onClick={this.registerHandler}
                positive={this.state.registerOn}
              >
                SignUp
              </Button>
              <Button.Or />
              <Button onClick={this.loginHandler} positive={this.state.loginOn}>
                Login
              </Button>
            </Button.Group>
          </div>
 <Provider store = {store}> <Register {...this.props} /> </Provider> // [[6]], uncommented [[4]] works but is it different than method [[1]]?
 //  <Register{...this.props} /> // [[2]] cannot connect to store
       // <Register store={store} {...this.props} />} [[1]] can connect store via directly sending store //
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



  // ReactDOM.render(<LoginContainer />,  document.getElementById("root")); [[answer]] removing this fixed the problem

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loggedIn: state.registration.isLoggedIn
  };
};

const mapDisptachToProps = dispatch => ({
  registerUser: id => dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN" })
});
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDisptachToProps
  )(LoginContainer)
);
```

```js
//components/register.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Local State

  }
   const check() {
   let userData: User;
    if (validEmail(this.state.email)) {
      userData = {
       //data 
      };

     let user = await this.handleSignUp(userData);
       const res = JSON.parse(user);

        if (res.message === "Success") {
          alert('Account success')
        }
      if(typeof user === 'string'){
         user =JSON.parse(user)
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ hiddenErrorMessage: false });
    }
    this.props.registerUser(userData);

    // func: returns true if it is valid, o.w. false
    function validEmail(email) {

    }
  };
  //handlers()

  render() {
    return (
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-filename-extension
      <div>
        <Input
          className="customInput"
          onChange={this.handleEmail}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <Input
          className="customInput"
          onChange={this.handlePassword}
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
        />
        <br />
        <Button
          size="big"
          className="customButton"
          onClick={this.checkUserInput}
        >
          Sign up
        </Button>
        <p>
          <span hidden={this.state.hiddenErrorMessage}>
            Invalid Email/Passoword
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

 return {
   loggedIn:state.registration.isLoggedIn
 }
};

const mapDisptachToProps = dispatch => ({
  registerUser: id =>  dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN" }) // return dispatch
});

export default Register // [[3]] Works as expected
// export default connect( [[4]] Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Register)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider> Error
//   mapStateToProps,
//   mapDisptachToProps
// )(Register);
```

```js
//store.js 

import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

```js
//reducers/index.js

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import registration from "./registration";

export default combineReducers({ registration });
```

```js
//actionType.js
const SIGN_IN = 'SIGN_IN';

export { SIGN_IN };
```

```js
//reducers/registration.js

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isLoggedOut: false,
  userId : ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "SIGN_IN") {
    return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true };
  }
  if (action.type === "SIGN_OUT") {
    return { ...state, isLoggedOut: true };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: when do you call `registerUser`?, the problem is probably on calling an action from `Register` component, looking at it, the `registerUser` is the only action out there, if you comment that one, does the app run successfully?

Comment: @SultanH. I call it in one of my handlers in the Register component, after it makes a Fetch to my server and gets some data from it. I tried removing unfortunately it gives me the same error. I updated the code to reflect some changes

Comment: Can you please check the answer below AGAIN, I have updates for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem was removing the next code from the `LogainContainer`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<LoginContainer />,  document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I replaced it with the code snippet. Changes should be reflected in my code above. It still is not able to connect but that's one less possible cause.

Comment: Another possibility, `const root = document.getElementById("root");
if (root !== null) {
  ReactDOM.render(<LoginContainer />, root);
}` in `LoginContainer`,,, why are you doing this?

Comment: Maybe wrapping the `LoginContainer` with `Provider` the same way in the `index.js` as we wrapped the `<App />` will fix it.

Comment: I really advice you remove the whole thing instead of wrapping it with a provider, the whole `if(root!==null)` block, it not only takes away the `store`, but also the router, and so on, it loses all the context given in the `index.js` for the whole app.

Comment: You are awesome. Removing ```ReactDOM.render(<LoginContainer />,  document.getElementById("root"));```  from LoginContainer.js fixed the problem! I assume because it replaces the root div with loginContainer thereby removing the Provider or something? Thanks so much!

Comment: Woohoo, this made me happy!

Comment: Exactly! in `index.js` you wrap your app with both `BrowserRouter` & `Provider`, doing this bit of code will replace all the assertion of those in the `div id='root'` with only the `LoginContainer`, thus, you'll lose both the router and the store.

Comment: You may now mark this as a correct answer (the mark is under the vote options to the left of the answer), this way other users with the same problem may easily find out that this answer is what they need to solve the problem they have. and also will tell others who are willing to provide help know that this is over with.

Always great to help out!